# Windows Server 2003 Active Directory password reset

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, active-directory

Hi there i'm trying to reset windows server 2003 forgotten password.
Tried system rescue cd bootable linux

```
ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows –o force
chntpw -l SAM (this command dont show AD users, just local)
chntpw –u Administrator SAM
```

but this reset local Administrator password

Is there a way to reset Active Directory users passwords ??

Answer (score 1):

The 'typical' answer is to log on with another admin user and reset the password via active directory users and computers. Is there a reason you can't do this?

I haven't tested it but if you've locked out *all* your domain administrator accounts then you might give [this](http://www.petri.co.il/reset_domain_admin_password_in_windows_server_2003_ad.htm) a look.